# How to set up associations and tables for this type of application in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I want a user to be able to create a "note" that contains things like multiple text fields, images, graphs, and some others. (Just like a notebook for school)

I am creating these models:

- User
- Note
- Image
- Graph
- Text

  ```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :note
    has_many :notes
  end  

  class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user
    has_many :graphs
    has_many :images
  end

  class Graph < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :note
  end  

  class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :note
  end

  class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :note
  end
  ```

Would I do a joins tables like note_graph, note_image, etc. with the ids of each?

Users can have many notes,but notes can only have one user (viewed by anyone).

I want the text and the others to be contained with a note.

Please help :S

Comment: Can you be more specific with what your question is?

Comment: @Beerlington My question is, what is the correct way to build out my associations and database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Polymorphic Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) for this one.

The `Note` model would belong to `Graph`, `Image`, `Text` on single `notable` association and would also belong to `User`.

Your model definitions would then be defined as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :notes
end  

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Graph < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :notes, as: :notable
end  

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes, as: :notable
end

class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes, as: :notable
end
```

Your migration for `Note` would then be something similar to:

```
class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
      t.integer :notable_id
      t.string  :notable_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Note the two columns, `notable_id` and `notable_type`.  `notable_type` would hold either one of `Graph`, `Image`or `Text` class name as string and `notable_id` would hold the corresponding class's `id`.

`Users` and `Notes` association would simply be "User has many notes" and "Note belongs to User".

Comment: Wow thanks! I've never used this type of association, so I hope I implement it correctly.